# SceneKit Particle System not appearing

Tags: swift, scenekit, particles, particle-system

I'm trying to add flames to a rocket by using a particle system in Scenekit. The particle file looks fine and I don't get any errors but the particles don't appear when I run the app.
Both reactor.scnp and spark.png are in the art.scnassets folder as well as the main app folder.

```
  @objc func sceneTapped(recognizer: UITapGestureRecognizer) {
        let location = recognizer.location(in: sceneView)

        let hitResults = sceneView.hitTest(location, options: nil)
        if hitResults.count > 0 {
            let result = hitResults[0] as! SCNHitTestResult
            let node = result.node

            let physicsBody = SCNPhysicsBody(type: .dynamic, shape: nil)
            rocket.physicsBody = physicsBody
            let direction = SCNVector3(0, 3, 0)


            let rocketshipNode = rocket

            let reactorParticleSystem = SCNParticleSystem(named: "reactor.scnp", inDirectory: nil) //SCNParticleSystem(coder: "art.scnassets/reactor")
            print(reactorParticleSystem)
                let engineNode = rocket.childNode(withName: "node2", recursively: false)
            print(engineNode)

            // 3
            physicsBody.isAffectedByGravity = false
            physicsBody.damping = 0

            // 4
            let collider = [floor]
            reactorParticleSystem?.colliderNodes = collider as? [SCNNode]
            // 5
            engineNode?.addParticleSystem(reactorParticleSystem!)

            // 6
            let action = SCNAction.moveBy(x: 0, y: 0.3, z: 0, duration: 3)
            action.timingMode = .easeInEaseOut
            rocketshipNode!.runAction(action)



        }
    }
```

Comment: no parent Node for engineNode. rootNode?.addChildNode(engineNode)

Comment: @E.Coms I get the error "Value of type 'SCNNode?' has no member 'rootNode'"

Comment: the rootNode is from scnscene. I mean the engineNode has no parent and will be removed when leaving the function domain.

Comment: I'm also getting nil for "reactorParticleSystem"

Comment: That means you did not get the "reactor.scnp" file.

Comment: Yeah I'm trying to figure out why it's not getting it because if I use the same code in a different project the particle system loads fine.

Comment: But here did any node addchildnode of engine ?

Comment: The engine node was already a child of rocketNote in the sun file. I recreated the Particle system file and it seems to work

Comment: It's great to heat that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Not sure what the issue was but I recreated the Particle System File and it seems to work fine.